# Correct usage of use in a sentence

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

Which one is grammatically correct?

> 1.There are two steps **to use** this system.
>   2.There are two steps **to using** this system.

Answer (score 3):

OP's first alternative sounds completely "off" to me. In such contexts, ***to*** isn't an "infinitive verb marker" - it's a preposition that effectively means ***[that are] involved in***<sup>1</sup>. Which simply doesn't work where the referent of the preposition is the ***verb*** phrase ***use this system***.

The second is better, because at least ***using this system*** is a credible ***noun*** phrase (a "gerund", if you like). But personally I'd prefer...

> 3: *There are two steps to **[the] use of** this system*

...where the target of the preposition is more explicitly "nouny".

---

<sup>1</sup> A few example utterances that might give a better picture of how ***to*** functions here...

> 4: *There's [more **to** this question](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22more%20to%20this%20question%22) than meets the eye*
>    5: *There are four key [elements **to** the plan](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22elements%20to%20the%20plan%22)*
>    6: *There are many [sides **to** this argument](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sides%20to%20this%20argument%22)*

...from which it should be clear that whatever follows ***to*** in such contexts should always be a ***noun***.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct in two senses but it depends on the people from different nations. In my opinion almost every ESL learners select the first one at once. But a native may easily select the second one ..